# how to add an image to a many2one field odoo12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

how to add an image(binary) to a many2one field other than "EHCS Many2one Dropdown Image"(module)

```
class x:
    x = field.binary()  #image
    name = field.char() #name

class y:
  m = field.many2one(class x)  #show(name image)
```

Comment: Why do you want to have many2one field to hold an image data instead of the field being binary field itself?